# How to manually sign Android apk with Google Play's App Signing certificate?

Tags: google-play, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I accidentally enabled Google Play's App Signing feature. But my app has a lot of 3rd party integration such as Firebase, Facebook login, etc. They all requires keyhash and SHA1. So developing, testing and deploying with 2 different signing keys is a big hassle.
Is there any way I can use the Google Play's certificate to sign my app during development? (Just for testing purpose).
Specifically I would want to create a keystore to be used in Unity3D from Google's certificate.
Thanks